# Querying a parent child referencing in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mongoose-schema

I have the comment model as:

```js
const commentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    content: String,
    score: Number,
    replyingTo: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment" },
  }
);
const Comment = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

I want to return a query like below. how can I do that?

```js
{
content:"s sample content for comment",
score:12,
replies:["644914e42dcb3e56cf9e8f4b" , "675fd4914e42dcb3edfr8f9e8f4b" ,"234fd4914e42dcb3edfr8dfr8f4b"]
}
```

I guess with virtual properties or aggregation framework can we do that

Comment: something like [this?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ROVyyA2PGCC)

Comment: should i add as an answer?

Comment: sure. it was what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the array of replies by doing a self `$lookup`. After that it is just a `$project`. Since your output has stringified object ids you might have to `$map` through the array and convert each `$toString`. If this is not needed you can just project `replies: "$replies._id"`

```js
db.comments.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "replyingTo",
      as: "replies"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      content: 1,
      score: 1,
      replies: {
        $map: {
          input: "$replies",
          as: "reply",
          in: {
            $toString: "$$reply._id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ROVyyA2PGCC)

Comment: how can I populate the replies field in a unlimited nested? I can populate the above result for the first level

Comment: @sasan not sure what is meant maybe something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g_2Fp06sCl4)